# Python 3.5 - Smart module imports in the file tree

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if it was possible for modules in a project to be smart about their imports...

Say I have the following data structure :

```
/parent-directory
    /package
        __init__.py
        main.py
        /modules
            __init__.py
            one.py
            /submodules-one
                __init__.py
                oneone.py
                onetwo.py
            two.py
```

Files higher in the hierarchy are supposed to import Classes from those lower in the hierarchy.

For instance main.py has

```
import modules.one
import modules.two
```

Now I'd like to be able to directly run not only main.py, but also one.py (and all the others)

Except that it doesn't work like I hoped :
If I run from main.py, I need to have in one.py

```
import modules.submodules-one.oneone
import modules.submodules-one.onetwo
```

But if I run from one.py, I'll get an error, and I need to have instead

```
import submodules-one.oneone
import submodules-one.onetwo
```

I've found a hacky way to get around it using in one.py :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import submodules-one.oneone
    import submodules-one.onetwo
else:
    import modules.submodules-one.oneone
    import modules.submodules-one.onetwo
```

But isn't there a better solution?

---

P.S.: I also have an additional complication, I'm using [pint](https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.2/tutorial.html),
which to work properly only needs to have a single instance of the unit registry, so I have in the top ____init____.py :

```
from pint import UnitRegistry
ur = UnitRegistry()
```

And obviously

```
from .. import ur
```

will fail if running from one of the files of the subfolders.

---

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: In general, it's best not to run modules in a package directly as scripts (with e.g. `python package/module.py`). Instead, use the `-m` flag to the interpreter: `python -m package.module`. Would that work for you?

Comment: @Blckknght, I finally decided that it was too much of an hassle, and used instead a "flat" structure ; the risk of circular references is probably not too high as long as I'm careful.